# React render array of components

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Quick question. Anyone know how to render an array of components? Trying to make it easier for a developer to alter a particular component. (It's like a dashboard).

Component list file

```
import React from 'react';
export default [
    <ComponentOne/>
    <ComponentTwo/>
];
```

Dashboard Component

```
import React from 'react';

import components from './../../components';

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component 
{
    render = () => {
        //Want to render the array of components here.
        return (
            <div className="tile is-parent">
                {components}
            </div>
        );
    };
}
```

The issue is I have an array of components that I need to add a key to. However! I can't seem to add a key to the component as well, not sure how to explain it really so here's the code I've tried:

```
{components.map((component, key) => (
    <component key={key}/>
}
```

If I do the above I get no 'you must apply a key' errors however nothing renders? And I'm guessing it's because 'component' doesn't exist or something weird along those lines.

I've also tried `component.key = key;` but it doesn't let me do that on this type of Object apparently?

My fallback I suppose is to return a shorthand function instead of an array but I like the array for some reason? Seems simpler for juniors.

Comment: You can't apply key to `component` as it will taken in as an attribute to the component.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you consider using the new [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)? (in v16)

This would be the simplest solution as it would by pass the whole array/key issue.

If you need to pass key, then I'd suggest to simply require the components to have the keys. This is how React works, so I wouldn't suggest you to hide this behavior behind an interface that might not be predictable.

If you really need to do this, then you can use [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to clone the element and inject new properties:

```
React.cloneElement(element, { key: 'foo' });
```

Answer (score 14):

If you’re always going to want to render all the components in your components file then you’re probably better off wrapping them in a React.Fragments tag.

Best practise is just to export this as a simple function that returns the components rather than as a constant.

So...

```
const Components = props => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>

      <ComponentOne/>
      <ComponentTwo/>

    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default Components
```

That allows you to put multiple components next to each other without a DOM element containing them.

You should then just be able to render that by using it as a normal component and it’ll render all of them, so just import it then...

```
<Components />
```

Otherwise, if you want to treat them like an array, you have a function for free on the React object you’ve imported...

```
React.Children.toArray(arrayOfComponents)
```

You pass it an array of components (like in your original question) and it allows you to sort and slice it if you need to then you should be able to just drop it in the return of your render function

Answer (score 9):

Following up with my comment, you should be doing this instead:

```
{components.map((component, index) => (
    <span key={index}>
        { component }
    </span>
}
```

With React 16, you can use `React.Fragment`:

```
{components.map((component, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
        { component }
    </React.Fragment>
}
```

Comment: Rather than using a span, you could also use `React.Fragment` to prevent having to add a parent container: <React.Fragment key={index}>{component}</React.Fragment>

Answer (score 4):

All of these answers are almost right. Just remove the `<../>` from your exports:

```
export default [
    ComponentOne,
    ComponentTwo,
]
```

And in the other file use `.map()`:

```
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    render = () => (
        <div className="tile is-parent">
            {components.map((Component, key) => (<Component key={key} />))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also note that if you wanted to use `Fragment` like others suggested you can just write `<>...</>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are exporting array of `elements` from the file. One way is to export array of component and render them like

```
import React from 'react';
export default [
    ComponentOne
    ComponentTwo
];
// Then following will work
{components.map((Component, key) => (
    // Remember to make first letter capital (in this case "c")
    <Component key={key}/>
}
```

The other way is to wrap the component in `div` like this

```
import React from 'react';
export default [
    <ComponentOne/>
    <ComponentTwo/>
];
// Then wrap in div
{components.map((component, key) => (
    <div key={key}>
      {component}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: the second way will not work, bc you cannot return something like this `< <Component/>/>`

Comment: @TheReason And the reason?

Comment: just updated a comment, you have to remove `<` & `/>` from elements of array component. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy, just wrap your component into `div` and pass `key` there as i did below:

```
const Example = ({components}) => (
  <div>
    {components.map((component, i) => <div key={i}>{component}</div>)}    
  </div>
)
```

[`Worked example`](http://jsfiddle.net/560fyjnp/530/)

Comment: Looking at your worked example. How could I make this work if my render section looked like this. where 
 `var items = [Foo, Baz]; let items: any[] = items.map(item => {
   //alert(tab);
   return ({item});
  });ReactDOM.render(
  <Example components={items}/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);`

Comment: sorry for the messy syntax, i made a fiddle that does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/208y7mwg/

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like that :

```
{components.map(component => component)}
```

It mappes your components to display them one by one.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `{components}`?

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand a bit more to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48131214/1137672). If you have an array of elements `elementArray` and you would like to pass props to it like callbacks etc. you would do something like this-

To create the component array somewhere-

```js
elementArray.push(<MyComponent/>);
```

And then in render-

```js
<div>
{
    elementArray.map((element,i) => {
       React.cloneElement(element, { key: i,  onClick: () => myOnclick(i)})
    })
}
</div>
```

The second argument to `React.cloneElement` is an object of all the props that you would pass to the component at the time of render.

Comment: `myOnclick` has no access to the component state this way, right?

Comment: Well, technically `myOnclick` should be a callback method in the current (parent) component. So in that case an action within `element` that fires `onClick` would fire `myOnclick` on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using react version above 16 you can create your list of component like that:

```
import React from 'react';

export const componentList = [ ComponentOne, ComponentTwo ];
```

and render them anywhere like that:

```
import React from 'react';

function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      {componentList.map((component, index) => (
        <div key={index}> {component && component.render()}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Unclear why this is v16+ specific. Seems like should work, based on [similar answers 2 years before this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48131271/2308683)

Answer (score 0):

If I put components inside an array, I usually do it like this:

```
const COMPONENTS = [
  <Foo />,
  <Bar />
]

[0, 1].map(item => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={item}>
          {COMPONENTS[item]}
        </React.Fragment>
      )
})
```

Comment: `map()` function already has an index, so you don't need `[0, 1]`. Just do `COMPONENTS.map((c, item) => )` . https://stackoverflow.com/a/64734864/2308683