# How do I render a component for each object in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component. I have an array of objects.

const talents = [{...}, {...}]

I also return the following components:

```
      <Card>
    <Accordion>
      <Card >
        <Accordion.Toggle
          as={Card.Header}
          eventKey="0"
        >
          some title
        </Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
          <Card.Body>
            <Container>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
            </Container>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    </Accordion>
    <Link to="/home">
      <Button>
        Home
      </Button>
    </Link>
  </Card>
```

What I am trying to do is return the Accordion component for every object in the array.

What ive tried so far.

In the card component i ran a map() on the array:

```
<Card>
{talents.map(()=> {
return (
<Accordion>
  <Card >
    <Accordion.Toggle
      as={Card.Header}
      eventKey="0"
    >
      some title
    </Accordion.Toggle>
    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
      <Card.Body>
        <Container>
          <div>title</div>
          <p>words</p>
          <div>title</div>
          <p>words</p>
          <div>title</div>
          <p>words</p>
          <div>title</div>
          <p>words</p>
        </Container>
      </Card.Body>
    </Accordion.Collapse>
  </Card>
</Accordion>
)
})}

<Link to="/home">
  <Button>
    Home
  </Button>
</Link>
</Card>
```

Nothing happens.

I also tried to create a function that maps throught the array and returns the jsx, and then just run the function inside the card component, like this:

```
const renderTalents = () => {

talents.map(() => (
        <Accordion>
      <Card >
        <Accordion.Toggle
          as={Card.Header}
          eventKey="0"
        >
          some title
        </Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
          <Card.Body>
            <Container>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
            </Container>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    </Accordion>
))
}
```

Then i ran the function in card component like this:

```
<Card>
renderTalents()
</Card>
```

Again, nothing happens.

Also wrapped the function in {}:

```
<Card>
{renderTalents()}
</Card>
```

Nothing.

Comment: `talents.map(...)` would return blank if `talents` had zero elements.  Are you `console.log(...)` each iteration, to verify you do have the element?  Maybe try that to check your `map()`ing is working right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React render array of components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131100/react-render-array-of-components)

Comment: How are you defining `talents`?

Comment: I did console log and talents holds 2 objects.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger talents is an empty array that on a useEffect hook gets populated with objects from a mono dadabase. I console log talents at the end of the hook and it shows the objects. i then ran the map function and just had it console log the objects and it does.

Comment: Console.log(objects) points to the objects reference, which could be different at different points in execution (console.log(objects) when objects is undefined will show the objects if they are eventually filled by the end of the script).  This is why logging static text would help you determine when and where it actually does get filled.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger ahh. I set static objects in talents then ran the same map function and it indeed worked as intended. I thought that useEffect runs before component loads, so i assumed that the data would be available when it was time to return my components. I guess i need to figure out how to make sure the data is loaded before i return my component. Thanks for the help! Although i still have a problem, the question was answered.

Comment: @ben Excellent!  Glad to have helped!  I tried to put all the wisdom we gathered here into an answer below so it can help someone help.  Feel free to accept it, if all is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `talents` is empty, then you will always get a blank result from `talents.map()`.

```js
var arr1 = [];

console.log("Results: |" + arr1.map(()=>{}).join('') + "|");
```

Don't forget that `console.log(object)` will show the result of the object at the end of runtime, too, and not at the moment it is called.  You can get around that with `console.log(JSON.stringify(object))`, if there are no recursive references.

Answer (score 0):

@ben, It looks like you are not using the `talents` array items you are mapping. The Arrow function that you are passing to the [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is called for each item in the array, with the first parameter being the item and the next one being the key.

You are not using the item. Take an example of some talents below...(they can be anything you want)

```js
const talents = [
  {title: 'React', skill: 'Expert'},
  {title: 'React Native', skill: 'Pro'},
  {title: 'Public Speaking', skill: 'Novice'},
];

// So mapping over talents would result it
const renderTalents => talents.map(({
  title, skill
}) => (
  <Accordion key={title}>
    <Card >
      <Accordion.Toggle
        as={Card.Header}
        eventKey="0"
      >
        {title}
      </Accordion.Toggle>
      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
        <Card.Body>
          <Container>
            <div>{skill}</div>
          </Container>
        </Card.Body>
      </Accordion.Collapse>
    </Card>
  </Accordion>
));
```

Comment: Please add a key prop to the outermost element in of the map. Something like <Accordion key={title} > ... </Accordion>  

Please refer to this: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score -1):

You missed the return before the map.

```
const renderTalents = () => {

  return talents.map(() => (
        <Accordion>
      <Card >
        <Accordion.Toggle
          as={Card.Header}
          eventKey="0"
        >
          some title
        </Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
          <Card.Body>
            <Container>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
              <div>title</div>
              <p>words</p>
            </Container>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    </Accordion>
))
}
```

Comment: You're right, OP did miss the `return()` there, but the other code sample posted had a `return()`, and that, similarly, was failing.  Anyway, OP has massively updated their answer anyhow.

Comment: You've missed the 'element' inside map(). it should be something like this : 
map((element) => <p> element<p>).